# Matlab GUI roipoly on multiple axes

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

If I've multiple `axes` on my `Matlab GUI` window, and each one of them has a different image.

How can I manage to do `roipoly` function on each of them ?

This solution should be without recalling `imshow` then `roiploy` after it for each one of them since:

- All images are show on `axes` using a loop that if I processed axes one after one the `GUI` would appear so ugly.
- Re-doing `imshow` will cost time as images are very large and they are processed each time before being shown, so it'll be a ver bad solution to waste time in a repeated processing.

Comment: You appear to have a working method, what is the problem with doing it one by one?

Comment: I need to simply invoke `roipoly` on an image shown on some `axes` with a handle *hAxes* , My current way to to do is to re `imshow` then do `roipoly` directly after showing the image, and all my gui axes are drawn in a loop that if I used my previous method the gui would appear to be ugly and also images are very large that it would consume time to reload them, I need a solution to do `roipoly` on them without need to reload them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `impoly` instead of `roipoly`:

```
polyH = impoly( hAxes );
position = wait( polyH );
```

Please see Matlab's doc on `impoly` for more functionality.